# Animate package: draft mode does not work

Tags: beamer, errors, animate

I'm using the `animate` package with Beamer and would like to use draft mode to cut down the compilation time.  However, it seems that the draft option causes compilation to fail.  Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[draft]{animate}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Frame title}
    \begin{animateinline}{6}
        \multiframe{41}{i=0+1}{
            frame \i
        }
    \end{animateinline}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The error is `Missing number, treated as zero` on the `\end{frame}` line:

```
./mwe.tex:11: Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \setbox 
l.11 \end{frame}

A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

./mwe.tex:11: Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
                    \setbox 
l.11 \end{frame}

Dimensions can be in units of em, ex, in, pt, pc,
cm, mm, dd, cc, bp, or sp; but yours is a new one!
I'll assume that you meant to say pt, for printer's points.
To recover gracefully from this error, it's best to
delete the erroneous units; e.g., type `2' to delete
two letters. (See Chapter 27 of The TeXbook.)

./mwe.tex:11: Missing { inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \unitlength 
l.11 \end{frame}
```

There are a bunch more errors after that.  I'm compiling using `xelatex` but I get the same error using `pdflatex`. I also get the same error using `\documentclass{article}` so it's not Beamer's fault.

Comment: I run your code using pdflatex in TeXstudio and I did not get any error!

Comment: A new version [`[2016/05/30]`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/animate) is available on CTAN which fixes the issue.

Comment: Confirming the update fixed this problem. Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is related to a bug in a package that has been fixed meanwhile.